# Knockout External Template Value Reset

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-templating

Am using Knockout External Template
https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine

But how to clear newly binded value and text from External template.
my html code something like this

**HTML**

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'RegistrationForm.html' }"></ul>
 <div data-bind="click:Add"></div>
```

**Scripts**
When i click add, Form Value from 'RegistrationForm.html'  will bind to a grid, but on the same time i need to clear all bind value from 'RegistrationForm.html'.
Assume i have many fields and some text binding on the selected template.
so my question how to clear bind text and form value from Templates when on button click.

**Actual Scenario :**

> When opened a  user template then value and text
>   related to the corresponding user will bind to that template. but when
>   i click next user with out any value the first user vale remains
>   there. am using one template for all user)

thanks

**EDIT** 
*My code like this structure*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Templates</title>
        <style>
            .clear {
                clear: both;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/koExternalTemplateEngine_all.js"></script>
        <script>
                    $(function(){
                    function pop1(data)
                    {
                    this.a = ko.obeservable(data.a || '');
                            this.b = ko.obeservable(data.b || '');
                    }
                    function pop2(data)
                    {
                    this.c = ko.obeservable(data.c || '');
                            this.d = ko.obeservable(data.d || '');
                    }
                    Viewmodel = function(){
                    self = this;
                            self.obj = new Object();
                            self.name = {
                            id:1
                                    name:'test'
                            };
                            self.types = [
                            {
                            id:1
                                    name:'test'
                            },
                            {
                            id:2
                                    name:'test2'
                            }

                            ];
                            self.whichPopup = fucntion(){
                    switch (name()){
                    case '1':
                            //Load Template for this option
                            //This wil b a user form with some value will bind when on laod
                            var data {}; // data with a and b
                            self.obj = new pop1(data);
                            break;
                            case '2':
                            //Load Template for this option
                            var data {}; // data with c and d
                            self.obj = new pop1(data);
                            break;
                    }
                    };
                    };
                    }); </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Temp">
            <div class="temp1">  
                <div data-bind="template:{name : 'Template1.html'}"></div>  
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="temp2">                 
                <div data-bind="template:{name : 'Template2.html'}"></div>              
            </div>  
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <select class="submission_type"
                    data-bind="options: types,
                                   optionsText : 'name',                               
                                   value: name,
                                   optionsCaption:'---Select---'
                    ">
            </select>
            <div data-bind="template:{name : whichPopup}"></div>
            <!--  This part working -->
            <!--
             Table here
             i need to add multiple entried here,
            so will add users here

             1- Select type
             2- Tempalte will opened in a popup
             3- Save to,then dispaly to the grid
            -->


            <!--
              1- Selcted option type that i hav already added before for to add same type but diffrent user
              2- popup1 will opened
              3- but it have the values that i have first time added
              4- if it was text box only then i can clear but it have some text binding to a div too
            -->
        </div>  

    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
I have changed the concept, let me know how to disable caching template in knockout External template.
so far i have tried :

```
infuser.defaults.ajax.cache = false
```

but not working,i just need to refresh the template.
thanks

Comment: is it possible to make a sample repro fiddle on this .

Comment: let me guess `RegistrationForm.html` will have observables binded against elements right , on `add` function simply clear like `self.name("")` etc

Comment: let me try for a fiddle.

Comment: @supercool its difficult to add fiddle  but my code like this

Comment: please read all commented lines..then you can undrstand.thanks

Comment: In short how to clear form field from the above structure.

Comment: still its very hard looking at the bits & pieces , if once entered values in pop coming up again after reusing the popup , then you should try clearing the `observables` binded to popup before popup loads (find what triggering popup to appear and clear before it appears ).

Comment: i have tried to clean the observable by setting null value. but not working

Comment: i have tried self.obj.a(null);  but not working as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80377/discussion-between-super-cool-and-muhammed-uvais).